# No sass qual a diferença entre um mixin e um placeholder?

Tags: css3, sass

Os dois tem o mesmo resultado final, mas nao sei qual é o correto ou o que tem melhor perfornace
exemplo:

```
%borda($circunferencia: 10px) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $circunferencia;
  border-radius: $circunferencia;
}

@mixin borda($circunferencia: 10px) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $circunferencia;
  border-radius: $circunferencia;
}
```

Comment: costumo usar mixin mas ja vi gente usando placeholder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## ***mixins***

Permitem que você defina estilos que podem ser reutilizados em toda a folha de estilo. Permite reproduzir regras `CSS` completas em um documento `Sass` e até mesmo ter argumentos que permite que você produza uma grande variedade de estilos com muito poucos `mixins`.

Imagine que você tenha algumas declarações que são repetidas várias vezes em sua folha de estilo e você sabe que a repetição do código é muito ruim e trabalhosa. Para contornar isso escreva `mixins` para essas declarações repetidas.
Vamos a um exemplo:

```
@mixin center() {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container {
  @include center();
}

.image-cover {
  @include center();
}
```

Dessa forma  você não tem que repetir aquelas três linhas cada vez que você precisar aplicar á um elemento, você simplesmente inclui o `mixin`.

Um exemplo muito comum em folhas de estilos são a definição do `Width e Height` de elementos, esse problema pode ser resolvido com um `mixin`, por exemplo.

```
@mixin size($width, $height: $width) {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
}
```

`$height`por default têm o mesmo valor que o `$width` e sempre que você precisar definir altura e largura, você pode fazer isto:

```
.icon {
  @include size(32px);
}

.cover {
  @include size(100%, 10em);
}
```

## ***Placeholders***

São classes que não são geradas quando o `SCSS` é compilado.

Exemplo:

```
%center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Parecido com a `classe` que usamos em `CSS`, exceto pelo prefixo com o `%` em vez de um `.`. Além disso seguem as mesmas regras de nomenclatura que as classes.

Agora, se você tentar compilar seu `Sass/CSS`, você não verá esse exemplo de código no arquivo gerado.

Esse código é inútil até que você use `@extend` que visa herdar propriedades de um seletor `CSS/SCSS.`

Veja como usá-lo:

```
.container {
  @extend %center;
}
```

Ao fazer isso, o *Sass* irá obter o conteúdo do `%center` e aplicá-lo ao `.container`. Você também pode estender os seletores `CSS`, assim:

```
.table-zebra {
  @extend .table;

  tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  }
}
```

Este é um caso muito comum para a `@extend`. Neste caso, pedimos que a `.table-zebra` classe se comporte exatamente como a `.table` classe e, em seguida, adicionamos as regras específicas da `zebra`. Estender os seletores é muito conveniente quando você desenvolve seu site/sistema em componentes modulares.

## **Qual deles usar?**

Depende do contexto e do que você está tentando fazer.

Resumindo se você precisar de variáveis com um código mais flexível/dinâmico/preciseDeAlteracao, use um `mixin`, ao contrário, se precisa de um código agrupado `placeholder`.

**Há duas razões para isso:**

1. Você não pode usar variáveis ​​em um placeholder. Até que pode, mas você não pode passar variáveis ​​para seus métodos para que você não pode gerar `CSS` específicas do contexto como você faria com um `mixin`.
2. Como Sass manipula `mixins` torna muito inconveniente quando
   você não usá-los com variáveis. Para colocá-lo
   simplesmente: Sass irá duplicar a saída do mixin cada vez que você
   usá-lo, resultando não só em CSS duplicado, mas também em uma grande
   folha de estilo.

Considerando o primeiro exemplo de código, a saída CSS será:

```
.container {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.image-cover {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

**Observou o CSS duplicado?**

Isso não é ruim, mas se você tiver `mixins` em dezenas de linhas `SCSS` e sendo usado várias vezes em um projeto, essas três linhas poderiam facilmente  se tornar 300.

Agora com placeholder, o `CSS` gerado será:

```
.container, .image-cover {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

***Conseguiu perceber que aqui gerou um agrupamento em vez de duplicar o código?***

A compilação aproveita agrupamento selector sem quaisquer estilos repetidas. Portanto, sempre que você quiser evitar escrever as mesmas propriedades, sabendo que eles nunca vão mudar use `placeholder`. Isso resultará em uma folha de estilos compilada muito mais enxuta(com menos código).

Por outro lado, se você está disposto a escrever as mesmas propriedades em vários lugares, mas com valores diferentes `(tamanhos, cores, etc)` um `mixin` é o melhor. Se você tiver um grupo de valores fixos e valores de variáveis, você deve tentar uma combinação de ambos.

```
%center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

@mixin skin($color, $size) {
  @extend %center;
  background: $color;
  height: $size;
}

a { @include skin(pink, 10em) }
b { @include skin(blue, 90px) }
Neste caso, o mixin está estendendo o espaço reservado para valores fixos em vez de despejá-los diretamente em seu corpo. Isso gera CSS limpo:

a, b {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

a {
  background: pink;
  height: 10em;
}

b {
  background: blue;
  height: 90px;
}
```

## Recomendo o curso: [Learn Sass](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sass)

<sub>Fonte: [Sass: Sass Basics](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-mixin-placeholder/)</sub>

Comment: Exelente resposta, pelo que eu entendi o placeholder apenas é uma alternativa para o mixin quando lidamos com parâmetros fixos. Quando é preciso passar algum valor na chamada da função, o mixin é mais recomendado

Comment: @JulianodaSilvaBarbosa Obrigado, o `placeholder` é mais aplicável aqueles estilos que se repetem bastante. Já o `mixin` aos estilos que precisam ser alterados. .Lembrando que o `mixin` quando chamado produz mais código, já o `placeholder` o código é agrupado

Comment: eu usava mixin mesmo com parâmetros fixos, vc sabe me dizer se existe alguma perda na performace ou algum problema que pode ser gerado no futuro? Pois se for o caso  tenho que alterar todos os meus codigos em varios projetos

Comment: @JulianodaSilvaBarbosa pela entendimento, quando for gerado o CSS todo elemento que você chamou com `mixin` irá duplicar o código. Já com o `placeholder` o código seria agrupado. Coloquei um exemplo da saída do CSS nos dois exemplos.

Comment: Obrigado novamente, agora ficou mais claro estou perdendo performace na compilação com mixin e no placeholder nao é compilado, aos poucos vou refatorar todos meus mixins